# Creating JSON RPC requests in Java with parameters which have parameters

Tags: java, json, json-rpc

The title is a bit messy, but what I'm trying to do is create a JSON RPC request which looks like this:

```
{
    "method":"site/method",
    "id":1,
    "filter":{
        "name":"person"
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to do that. I'm using the JSONRPCBase library right now but I'm not sure it's compatible with that. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You mean using objects as parameters? Either just pass the object or a Map<String,Object> or whatever your lib may except

Comment: Yeah, the objects. I managed to figure it out using gson.

Answer (score 0):

Your request structure is not JSON-RPC compliant.

For [JSON-RPC 2.0](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#request_object), try:

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0"
  "method": "site/method",
  "id": 1,
  "params": {
    "filter": {
      "name": "person"
    }
  }
}
```

For [JSON-RPC 1.0](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification), the parameters must to be an array, depending on your method arguments, so it can vary depending on your implementation. For example:

```
{
  "method": "site/method",
  "id": 1,
  "params": [{
    "filter": {
      "name": "person"
    }}]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "method": "site/method",
  "id": 1,
  "params": [{
      "name": "person"
    }]
  }
}
```